# Can I set ng-model to two values?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have an input

```
<input type="text" ng-model="choice.text">
```

Where `choice.text` creates a new text property in the object choice. This allows me to send the contents of the input to different page. While this feature works, I would also like to add another feature where the content of the input is displayed and updated in real time on the page. Something to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_intro) effect.

Unfortunately, `ng-model` is already set to `choice.text`. Is there a way I can have set two values to one `ng-model`? It would perhaps look like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="choice.text name"></p>
<p ng-bind="name"></p>
```

If not, is there another way to achieve this effect?

EDIT: For those wondering, when I try `<p ng-bind="choice.text"></p>`it doesnt work for some reason.

EDIT 2: I simplified the code for the sake of the question. Here is the actual code for more detail:

```
<div class ="ask-container">
    <div ng-switch="cbstate">
      <div ng-switch-when="not-pressed">
        <h1>Choose between... </h1> <!-- I would like to add the dynamic element here -->
      </div>
      <div ng-switch-when="pressed">
        <h1>Hi</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form role="form" ng-submit="submitChoice()">
      <div class="input" ng-repeat="choice in poll.options">
        <input type="text"  ng-model="choice.text" placeholder="Choice {{$index+1}}"><br>
      </div>
      <button class="add" type="button" ng-click="addChoice()">+</button>
      <button class="create" type="submit">Create</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

EDIT 3: Same code, but with the ng-bind:

```
<div class ="ask-container">
    <div ng-switch="cbstate">
      <div ng-switch-when="not-pressed">
        <h1>Choose between... </h1>
      </div>
      <div ng-switch-when="pressed">
        <h1>Hi</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form role="form" ng-submit="submitChoice()">
      <div class="input" ng-repeat="choice in poll.options">
        <input type="text"  ng-model="choice.text" ng-change="temp=choice.text" placeholder="Choice {{$index+1}}"><br>
      </div>
      <button class="add" type="button" ng-click="addChoice()">+</button>
      <button class="create" type="submit">Create</button>
    </form>
    <p ng-bind="temp"></p>
    <p ng-bind="choice.text"></p>
</div>
```

Note: Somebody said that the ng-repeat may be messing with my scope. Maybe keep that in mind as you try and fix my problem.

Comment: Why not `<p ng-bind="choice.text"></p>`?

Comment: can you add in the `ng-bind` part also?

Comment: With the `ng-repeat="choice in list"` there will be `list.length` inputs and choices. Which `choice.text` do you want bind outside the `ng-repeat`?

Comment: For now, just list[0]. Eventually I will want them all to appear in a list but I can do that myself. For now I just want the first input to display in the bind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For now, just `list[0]`. Eventually I will want them all to appear in a list but I can do that myself. For now I just want the first input to display in the bind.

To have the first of the list appear in the bind:

```
<div class="input" ng-repeat="choice in poll.options">
  <input type="text"  ng-model="choice.text" placeholder="Choice {{$index+1}}" />
  <br>
</div>

<p ng-bind="poll.options[0].text"></p>
```

Each `<div>` in the `ng-repeat` has its own child scope with the `choice` property set to `poll.options[0]`, `poll.options[1]`, `poll.options[2]`, etc. Simply use those values in the parent scope.

Answer (score 2):

Use **ng-change** to update other model

```
<input type="text" 
       ng-model="choice.text" 
       ng-change="temp=choice.text"/>
```

Now for testing, use:

```
<p ng-bind="temp"></p>
<p ng-bind="choice.text"></p>
```

Comment: @how come this is a working soln? it throws an error and ans receives +1vote. Please can you post a working code.

Comment: But initial answer was misleading.. Please test your answer's before posting any code.

Comment: Yes. I tested after posting the answer. Apologies! 
#peace

Comment: And then in the html do I add <p ng-bind="temp"></p>?

Comment: @Ethernetz, yes!

Comment: It doesnt work either way for me. I put the $scope.$watch function in my controller and added a console.log(v) underneath $scope.temp = v. It logs undefined once the page loads, and doesnt log anything afterwards. What am I missing?

Comment: Edited post so you can see more of the code. I use ng-repeat, does this change anything?

Answer (score 2):

Is this not acceptable?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="choice.text"></p>
<p ng-bind="choice.text"></p>
```

Comment: Edited post. I tried that before posting and it doesnt work :(

Comment: @Ethernetz if this doesn't work, that means the scope is different between these 2 elements. Are they under different controllers? Are they surrounded by `ng-if` or `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Yes, they are surrounded by ng-repeat. Does this affect anything?

Comment: Edited post so now you can see that ng-repeat is being used.